# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate on model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

What's the purpose of a Mongoose schema if I'm doing an upsert with `findOneAndUpdate` call?

Everything I can find seems to indicate if I do a `findOneAndUpdate`, I need to reference the base schema instead of an instance.

Here's my setup:

```
const PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ssn: {
    type: Number,
    unique: true,
  },
  first: String,
  last: String
})

const Person = mongoose.model("Person", PersonSchema)
const person = new Person({ssn: 123456789, first: "Foo", last: "Bar"})
```

If I just do a save (and that ssn exists already, I'll get a 'unique' violation).

```
person.save();
```

Instead, I'm finding out that I need to do something like

```
const options = { upsert: true, new: true }
const query = { ssn: 123456789 }

Person.findOneAndUpdate(
  query,
  {
    ssn: 123456789,
    first: "Foo",
    last: "Bar"
  },
  options)
```

**OR**

```
const options = { upsert: true, new: true }
const query = { ssn: 123456789 }

const newPerson = Object.assign({}, person._doc)

// delete this so I don't get a conflict with Mongoose on the _id during insert
delete newPerson._id

Person.findOneAndUpdate(query, newPerson, options)
```

It seems like `findOneAndUpdate` doesn't care about the specific model (or instance) and is simply just a mechanism to get to the underlying MongoDB method.

Is that the case? Or am I missing something that should be obvious?